# Logical expression evaluation

Tags: c

I don't understand how to evaluate `w1` and `w1`.
I know `i>1` is 0, `j<0` is 0, `i<0` is 1, `j>0` is 1 and so on, but how do I associate these values?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = -1, j = -i;
    int w1, w2;
    w1 = (i > 0) && (j < 0) || (i < 0) && (j > 0);
    w2 = (i <= 0) || (j = 0) && (i >= 0) || (j <= 0);
    printf("%d", w1 == w2);
    return 0;
}
```

`w1=1` and `w2=0` but I know that is incorrect. Can someone explain in detail the process?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you show us: 1. Answer you got. 2. Answer you expected. 3. Process how you think expected answer should come out.

Comment: `j = 0` Did you mean `j == 0`?

Comment: @Zakk Excellent question. That their compiler probably already asked, tho :)

Comment: @chrslg Nope because the mainstream compilers based on gcc uses a stupid convention that `(j = 0)` should pass silently because it was written inside a parenthesis. Compilers with better diagnostics than the gcc-like ones warn for every assignment inside expressions/conditions, always, every time.

Comment: @Lundin Oh, I should have tried before. But indeed, no warning with gcc.

Comment: @chrslg  GCC's `-Wparenthesis` flag is worse than useless - it creates a false sense of security that GCC will warn on inadvertent use of an assignment in a conditional.  It'd be better if that warning didn't exist.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yep. Maybe one day gcc, clang and icx will have as good diagnostics for this as Turbo C, an ancient compiler made in the year 1989... The problem with gcc is that there's so much prestige invested in various bad decisions made over the years. And the problem with clang and icx is that they don't have a mind of their own, they are essentially just copycat products. The main motivation for creating clang was supposedly to give better diagnostics than gcc... yeah right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obfuscated code with a load of bad practice. The mainstream C compilers will tell you about some of the problems if compiling with max warnings enabled.

- It's considered bad practice to mix a lot of `&&` and `||` on a single line without parenthesis around their respective operands.
- It is also bad practice to use assignment inside complex expressions.

Relevant operator precedence here is: `()` parenthesis highest, then `&&`, then `||` and `=` has the lowest precedence. So your expressions are equivalent to this:

```
w1 = ((i > 0) && (j < 0)) || ((i < 0) && (j > 0));
w2 = (i <= 0) || ((j = 0) && (i >= 0)) || (j <= 0);
```

From there on you can replace each inner parenthesis subexpression with boolean logic values.

Note the cheeky `(j = 0)`! This is not equivalence but assignment. Also gcc-like compilers will sadly not warn for this. The only reason why the code is still well-defined despite that assignment, is because the logical AND and OR operators are guaranteed to be sequenced left-to-right and in this case `(expr1) || (expr2)` guarantees that the `expr1` containing the assignment is executed before `expr2` where that assigned variable is used again.

With that crappy assignment in mind, each sub-expression can be replaced as (remember `i=-1, j=1`):

```
w1 = ((0) && (0)) || ((1) && (1));
w2 = (1) || ((0) && (0)) || (1);
```

Again, note that `j=0` returns `0`, changes the value of `j` to `0` and then later down the line `j <= 0` now evaluates to `1`.

After the && have been evaluated (their right operand doesn't get evaluated in case the left one is 0), you end up with:

```
w1 = (0) || (1);
w2 = (1) || (0) || (1);
```

In the end `1==1`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) to have a complete view.

In your case you have this order.
First (<,>,<=,>=), then && and finally ||.

So in your example
(I assumed you have a typo in  `j=0` because you are asking about logical expressions so I changed that to `j==0`):

```
i=-1; j=1; // i=-1; j=-i

w1 = (i > 0) && (j < 0) || (i < 0) && (j > 0);
// first we evaluate  all the  <,>,<=,>= 
w1 = false   &&   false || true    &&  true 
// Then &&
w1 = false || true 
//And finally ||
w1 = true (1)

// With w2 is the same 
w2 = (i <= 0) || (j == 0) && (i >= 0) || (j <= 0);
w2 = true || false && false || false 
w2= true || false || true 
w2= true (1)

// If I don´t change your code, leaving the j=0 as @Lundin commented
w2 = (i <= 0) || (j = 0) && (i >= 0) || (j <= 0);
w2 = true || false && false || true // (j=0 makes j<=0 true )
w2= true || false || true 
w2= true (1)
```

and w1==w2 = true (1)

Comment: how did you get from : w1 = false && false || true && true to false || true -> true (1) and from w2 = true || false && false || false to  true || false || true -> true (1)  ?

Comment: So first I do && then II?

Comment: In the link included in the answer you can see that the precedence of Logic AND (&&) is 11, while the precedence of Logic OR (||) is 12. So yes, && is evaluated before (just before) ||

Comment: The example comes with a built-in obfuscation bomb... `j=0` gives result 0 but after that `j<= 0` is true. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Lundin. You're right, I've assumed it was a mistake, and I've responded based on it. I have written it in the answer.
If it's not the case, I'll edit the answer keeping the original code in mind

Comment: @Lundin. Ok, I see you answered too

Comment: You need to edit the part that says `false && false || false`, because that is... false :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first statement:

```
 w1 = (i > 0) && (j < 0) || (i < 0) && (j > 0);
```

As logical AND, or `&&`, has higher precedence than logical OR, or `||`, the above statement is equivalent to:

```
w1 = ((i > 0) && (j < 0)) || ((i < 0) && (j > 0));
```

Given the values:

```
i = -1, j = -i;
```

The statement becomes:

```
w1 = ((-1 > 0) && (1 < 0)) || ((-1 < 0) && (1 > 0));
```

Now, in Boolean form:

```
w1 = ((false) && (false)) || ((true) && (true));
```

We know that the second operand is not evaluated in logical AND if the first operand evaluates to false. So the statement becomes:

```
w1 = false || true;
```

which evaluates to 1.

---

Regarding the second statement:

```
w2 = (i <= 0) || (j = 0) && (i >= 0) || (j <= 0);
                 |
                 |

w2 = (i <= 0) || ((j = 0) && (i >= 0)) || (j <= 0);
                 |
                 |

w2 = (-1 <= 0) || ((j = 0) && (-1 >= 0)) || (0 <= 0);
```

NB that `j = 0` doesn't compare `j` and 0, it assigns 0 to `j`.

Now, in Boolean form:

```
w2 = (true) || ((false) && (false)) || (true);
                 |
                 |
w2 = (true) || (false) || (true);
```

which results in true, and 1 is assigned to `w2`.